# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.fastdata.persistence.PersistenceService

Tags: scala

```
trait PersistenceService  {
    def setData(x: Any): Unit
    def getData(x:Any) : Any
}

object ConfigurationLoader{
    var p_service: PersistenceService = null
    val persistence_db = component_props.getProperty("persistence_db")
    p_service = (persistence_db+"Service").asInstanceOf[PersistenceService]
}
```

How i can cast at runtime?

Comment: Please clarify your question, and reformat it to use a code block.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Tim, Actually i want type cast runtime value . and val persistence_db will be equal to "Persistence"

Comment: .. is this possible?

Comment: You cannot cast a String to a PersistenceService...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do by using reflection like below

Class.forName("fully qualified class name").newInstance()